# using fwrite in C to write integers stored in a structure into .txt file, but the numbers shows up as box when I open the .txt file

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I am using the fwrite to write integers stored in a structure into a .txt file. However, when I open the file, the numbers are not readable (become box):
Here is my code:

```
fp=fopen("pre-survey.txt", "a");
printf("name\n");
scanf("%s", &temp.name);
printf("q1:\n");
scanf("%d", &temp.q1);
printf("q2:\n");
scanf("%d", &temp.q2);
printf("q3:\n");
scanf("%d", &temp. q3);
fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
}
```

temp is a structure i declared:

```
struct pre_survey{ 
char name[20]; int q1; int q2; int q3; };
struct pre_survey temp; 
struct pre_survey get;
```

Any advice?

Comment: Please provide more context for your code - what is `temp`? Unless it's a  string, you're outputting raw data to a text file. Seeing as it looks like a struct, you should be writing `&temp.name`, and then string representations of `&temp.q1`, `&temp.q2`, etc - you  can generate those using `sprintf()`. Or you can use `fprintf()` and print the formatted string representations of those variables directly.

Comment: You can probably use fprintf().

Comment: @ random davis
temp is a structure i declared:

    struct pre_survey{
 char name[20];
 int q1;
 int q2;
 int q3;
};
  struct pre_survey temp;
  struct pre_survey get;

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "%s %d %d %d\n", temp.name, temp.q1, temp.q2, temp.q3);` instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: @BonnyYang If you clarify something, it's probably better to clarify it by editing your question.

Comment: fprintf worked. Thanks for the help!
Just a follow up question: isnt fprintf used for strings? why does it also work for writing integer values?

Comment: @BonnyYang In order to print the integer value to the file as a readable value, it needs to be formatted as a string. That's what fprintf is doing. Otherwise, notepad is going to treat the raw number you've written as ASCII values. fprintf always outputs a string, but it can accept many different types as inputs - the whole point of it is that it formats those into a readable string.

Comment: @RandomDavis Got it. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fprintf function.

Something like:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s, %d, %d, %d", temp.name, temp.q1, temp.q2, temp.q3);
```